# jaxb xml output format test

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, jaxb2

I am looking for to put sampleId tag as below using Jaxb.
What tag do I need to use (@XMLElement (or) @XMLType) ?

```
    <Testing>
        <testId sampleId="1">16683885</locId>
    </Testing>
```

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: You are probably looking for `@XmlAttribute`. But please provide an [MCVE], it will be easier to reason then.